# Handle rotation when navigate back to previous screen

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, xamarin

I implemented on single screen(controller)

```
public override void WillAnimateRotation (UIInterfaceOrientation toInterfaceOrientation, double duration)
{
    base.WillAnimateRotation (toInterfaceOrientation, duration);
    positionUIWidgets ();
}
```

This works OK. But if I rotate and go back to previous screen (I have a navigation controller), the previous screen won't change its layout to fit the orientation. It seems that I need to manually call my "positionUIWidgets()" and I don't know how to do it and I wonder if there is a proper way to do it like "WillAnimateRotation" hook function or something like it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm mistaken (and I'd very much like to be in this case) you can no longer manually dictate an orientation change for a single controller since iOS 6.0.

Instead you have to provide methods which can be queried and return the supported orientation modes. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/viewcontrollerpgforiphoneos/RespondingtoDeviceOrientationChanges/RespondingtoDeviceOrientationChanges.html

Answer (score 0):

try this one.

```
#import <objc/message.h>

if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] respondsToSelector:@selector(setOrientation:)]) {
 objc_msgSend([UIDevice currentDevice], @selector(setOrientation:),    UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait );
}
```

Comment: Can you add a description of why this works, instead of just dumping a bit code?

Comment: I don't understand the code. Could you explain a bit? Where does this code go and what it does?